# Automated diff reporting

Tags: diff, winmerge

I need a diff tool that has a command line option to create and save a diff report that looks easy to read, something like the html report produced by WinMerge. I have a few hundred files that I need to compare and it's not practical to have to open the files and manually and save the report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did find a tool that does exactly that: http://sourceforge.net/projects/diff2html

It's a bash script that uses *diff(1)* and creates an HTML page from the output with colour-coded diffs.

Comment: There is now [a matching tool available via npm](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html) as well, if you're into the whole javascript ecosystem thing. The examples left something to be desired; here's what I used to diff two SHAs (ignoring json files): `diff2html -- ea55ae04f7..e422c3fa5e -- ':!*.json'`

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the command line option in WinMerge? http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html

You might need to use something like AutoHotkey to automate saving the reports created by WinMerge: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: you could do it by command line. example: %winMergeExe%
c:\temp\log c:\temp\log2
 /r /e /f *.ahk 
 /x /xq 
 /s /u /minimize 
 -cfg Settings/DiffContextV2=0
 yourPath1 yourPath2